# como mostrar un ui-icon en primefaces cuando el valor de una variable es true o false?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tengo la siguiente tabla, que muestra valores tipo boolean y los muestra de esa manera

```html
<p:dataTable id="horarios" rendered="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.muestraHistorial}" var="consultaHorario" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{ConsultaPersonasUnidadFisicaComponent.listNivelesPersona2}">
  <p:column headerText="Ubi">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.unidadAdministrativa.cveIdUnidadAdmin}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Horario">

  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Vigencia">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecInicioNivel}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText> -
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Horario">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.horarioEntrada} - #{consultaHorario.horarios.horarioSalida}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Tol">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.toleranciaRetardo}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Max. Falta">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.horarios.toleranciaFalta}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Checa">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Lunes">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaLunes}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Martes">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaMartes}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Miercoles">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaMiercoles}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Jueves">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaJueves}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Viernes">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaViernes}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Sabado">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaSabado}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Domingo">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaDomingo}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Festivo">
    <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.checaFestivo}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Observaciones">

  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es que en lugar de que aparezca true or false
aparezca una paloma cuando sea true y un tache cuando sea false, asi como en esta tabla 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede hacer?, y como podria implementarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma agregas dos **outputText** dentro del **column** le pones un **rendered** si es **true** muestra el que tiene el icono de la paloma si es **false** el que tiene el icono del tache:

```
<p:column headerText="Lunes">
   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed"  rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaLunes eq true}" />
   <h:outputText styleClass="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-document"  rendered="#{consultaHorario.checaLunes eq false}"/>
</p:column>
```

Los iconos que puse como ejemplo es un folder o un documento dependiendo la condición. Los iconos los puedes encontrar [Aqui](https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/)

Comment: excelente, gracias!